# Retriving Values and sum them from a table coulm which is in NESTED Json Format- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-athena, presto

Hi I'm trying to retrieve values from a Nest Json Column of a table and sum them. Which look's like below,

```
ID      Details    Created_At
2345               2021-05-31
3243               2021-06-02
3243               2021-06-02
3243               2021-06-02
```

Here the 'Details' column is the one which has json values in it per row, in below format

```
{
    "new_products": [
        {
            "bucket": "READY",
            "sku": "46123445323423",
            "overaged": 0,
            "transfer": 0,
            "total_count": 14,
            "actual_count": 14,
            "lock_quantity": 0
        },
     ],
    "old_products": [
        {
            "bucket": "READY",
            "sku": "451902224524",
            "overaged": 0,
            "transfer": 0,
            "total_count": 59,
            "actual_count": 59,
            "lock_quantity": 0
        },
        {
            "bucket": "READY",
            "sku": "46123445323423",
            "overaged": 0,
            "transfer": 0,
            "total_count": 14,
            "actual_count": 14,
            "lock_quantity": 0
        },
        {
            "bucket": "READY",
            "sku": "42342361484",
            "overaged": 0,
            "transfer": 0,
            "total_count": 29,
            "actual_count": 29,
            "lock_quantity": 0
        },
        {
            "bucket": "READY",
            "sku": "23234234342",
            "overaged": 0,
            "transfer": 0,
            "total_count": 57,
            "actual_count": 57,
            "lock_quantity": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

What i have been able to achieve in my query :

```
SELECT ID,
            Created_At,
          (json_extract(Details,'$.old_products') )  AS column
   FROM Table)
```

This just extracts 'old_products' values in a new column,

But, I'm trying to sum all the values of total_count , actual_count from key 'old_products','new_products' of every row into a new column.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Select one DBMS - either MySQL or RedShift. For MySQl - specify precise version. Provide sample data not as a value but as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: can you share the sample output based on your sample data?